# open().read() function returns empty string when called for second time, even after reopening the file: Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code:

```py
def Open_Settings():
    global Configurations
    
    Settings_Window = Toplevel()
    Settings_Window.config(background = "#000014")
    Settings_Window.title("Space Shooter: Settings")
    Settings_Window.iconphoto(False, Settings_Window_Icon)
    
    Setting_Frame = Frame(Settings_Window, height = 873, width = 810, background = "#000014")
    Setting_Frame.pack()
    
    try:
        Player_1 = Image.open("Images\\Player_Space_Ship(1).png")
        Player_1 = Player_1.resize((60, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        Player_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Player_1)
        Player_2 = Image.open("Images\\Player_Space_Ship(2).png")
        Player_2 = Player_2.resize((60, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        Player_2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Player_2)
        Player_3 = Image.open("Images\\Player_Space_Ship(3).png")
        Player_3 = Player_3.resize((60, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        Player_3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Player_3)
        Enemy_1 = Image.open("Images\\Enemy_Space_Ship(1).png")
        Enemy_1 = Enemy_1.resize((60, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        Enemy_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Enemy_1)
        Enemy_2 = Image.open("Images\\Enemy_Space_Ship(2).png")
        Enemy_2 = Enemy_2.resize((60, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        Enemy_2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Enemy_2)
        Enemy_3 = Image.open("Images\\Enemy_Space_Ship(3).png")
        Enemy_3 = Enemy_3.resize((60, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        Enemy_3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Enemy_3)
        Boss_1 = Image.open("Images\\Boss_Space_Ship(1).png")
        Boss_1 = Boss_1.resize((120, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        Boss_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Boss_1)
        Boss_2 = Image.open("Images\\Boss_Space_Ship(2).png")
        Boss_2 = Boss_2.resize((120, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        Boss_2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Boss_2)
    
    except Exception as Error:
        Alert.showerror("Files not Found", "Error: " + str(Error) + "\nRequired files not found at destination.")
        Settings_Window.destroy()
        return
    
    Settings_Config = Configurations
    
    Title = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Settings", background = "#000014", foreground = "#FFFFFF", font = ("Times New Roman", 36))
    Title.place(x = 333, y = 3)
    Appear_Title = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Appearence", background = "#000014", foreground = "#FFFFFF", font = ("Times New Roman", 30, "bold", "italic", "underline"))
    Appear_Title.place(x = 3, y = 54)
    Start_Appear_Title = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Start Window", background = "#000014", foreground = "#FFFFFF", font = ("Times New Roman", 24, "bold", "italic"))
    Start_Appear_Title.place(x = 27, y = 108)
    Change_Obj_Col_Label = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Change Object Colour with every Movement:", foreground = "#FFFFFF", background = "#000014", font = ("Times New Roman", 18))
    Change_Obj_Col_Label.place(x = 54, y = 153)
    Change_Obj_Col_Box = ttk.Combobox(Setting_Frame, values = ("Yes", "No"), font = ("Times New Roman", 12, "italic"), state = "readonly")
    Change_Obj_Col_Box.place(x = 567, y = 150)
    Start_Win_Bg_Label = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Start Window Background Colour:", foreground = "#FFFFFF", background = "#000014", font = ("Times New Roman", 18))
    Start_Win_Bg_Label.place(x = 54, y = 189)
    Start_Win_Bg_Box = ttk.Combobox(Setting_Frame, values = ("Space_Blue", "Black"), font = ("Times New Roman", 12, "italic"), state = "readonly")
    Start_Win_Bg_Box.place(x = 567, y = 186)
    Game_Appear_Title = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "After Game Starts", background = "#000014", foreground = "#FFFFFF", font = ("Times New Roman", 24, "bold", "italic"))
    Game_Appear_Title.place(x = 27, y = 234)
    Player_Label = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Player Ship Skin:", background = "#000014", foreground = "#FFFFFF", font = ("Times New Roman", 18)).place(x = 54, y = 288)
    Player_Label = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Enemy Ship Skin:", background = "#000014", foreground = "#FFFFFF", font = ("Times New Roman", 18)).place(x = 54, y = 378)
    Player_Label = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Boss Ship Skin:", background = "#000014", foreground = "#FFFFFF", font = ("Times New Roman", 18)).place(x = 54, y = 468)
    Player_1_Button = Button(Setting_Frame, image = Player_1)
    Player_1_Button.place(x = 261, y = 279)
    Player_2_Button = Button(Setting_Frame, image = Player_2)
    Player_2_Button.place(x = 360, y = 279)
    Player_3_Button = Button(Setting_Frame, image = Player_3)
    Player_3_Button.place(x = 459, y = 279)    
    Enemy_1_Button = Button(Setting_Frame, image = Enemy_1)
    Enemy_1_Button.place(x = 261, y = 369)
    Enemy_2_Button = Button(Setting_Frame, image = Enemy_2)
    Enemy_2_Button.place(x = 360, y = 369)
    Enemy_3_Button = Button(Setting_Frame, image = Enemy_3)
    Enemy_3_Button.place(x = 459, y = 369)
    Boss_1_Button = Button(Setting_Frame, image = Boss_1)
    Boss_1_Button.place(x = 261, y = 459)
    Boss_2_Button = Button(Setting_Frame, image = Boss_2)
    Boss_2_Button.place(x = 399.6, y = 459)
    Star_Appearence_Label = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Star Appearence:", foreground = "#FFFFFF", background = "#000014", font = ("Times New Roman", 18))
    Star_Appearence_Label.place(x = 54, y = 540)
    Star_Appearence_Box = ttk.Combobox(Setting_Frame, values = ("No Stars", "Stars but no Movement", "Stars with Movement"), state = "readonly", font = ("Times New Roman", 12, "italic"))
    Star_Appearence_Box.place(x = 567, y = 537)
    Game_Win_Bg_Label = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Game Window Background Colour:", foreground = "#FFFFFF", background = "#000014", font = ("Times New Roman", 18))
    Game_Win_Bg_Label.place(x = 54, y = 576)
    Game_Win_Bg_Box = ttk.Combobox(Setting_Frame, values = ("Space_Blue", "Black"), font = ("Times New Roman", 12, "italic"), state = "readonly")
    Game_Win_Bg_Box.place(x = 567, y = 576)
    Game_Func_Title = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Game Functionings", background = "#000014", foreground = "#FFFFFF", font = ("Times New Roman", 30, "bold", "italic", "underline"))
    Game_Func_Title.place(x = 3, y = 630)
    Player_Speed_Label = Label(Setting_Frame, text = "Player Ship Speed:", foreground = "#FFFFFF", background = "#000014", font = ("Times New Roman", 18))
    Player_Speed_Label.place(x = 54, y = 690)
    Player_Speed_Box = ttk.Combobox(Setting_Frame, values = ("Low", "Medium (Recommanded)", "High"), state = "readonly", font = ("Times New Roman", 12, "italic"))
    Player_Speed_Box.place(x = 270, y = 687)
    
    def Show_Curen_Config(Widget, Character, Image_Path = None):
        if Widget == "Button":
            if Character == "Player":
                if Configurations["Appearence"]["Game"]["Player_Ship_Image"] == Image_Path:
                    return "Red"
                else: 
                    return "White"
            if Character == "Enemy":
                if Configurations["Appearence"]["Game"]["Enemy_Ship_Image"] == Image_Path:
                    return "Red"
                else: 
                    return "White"
            if Character == "Boss":
                if Configurations["Appearence"]["Game"]["Boss_Ship_Image"] == Image_Path:
                    return "Red"
                else: 
                    return "White"
        if Widget == "Combobox":
            if Character == "#000000" or Character == False or Character == "Stars but no Movement" or Character == 4:
                return 1
            elif Character == "#000014" or Character == True or Character == "No Stars" or Character == 8:
                return 0
            else: 
                return 2
    
    def Change_Settings(Character, Name, Number = 1):
        
        if Character == "Player":
            Player_1_Button.configure(background = "White")
            Player_2_Button.configure(background = "White")
            Player_3_Button.configure(background = "White")
            Name.configure(background = "Red")
            Settings_Config["Appearence"]["Game"]["Player_Ship_Image"] = "Images\\Player_Space_Ship(" + str(Number) + ").png"
        if Character == "Enemy":
            Enemy_1_Button.configure(background = "White")
            Enemy_2_Button.configure(background = "White")
            Enemy_3_Button.configure(background = "White")
            Name.configure(background = "Red")
            Settings_Config["Appearence"]["Game"]["Enemy_Ship_Image"] = "Images\\Enemy_Space_Ship(" + str(Number) + ").png"
        if Character == "Boss":
            Boss_1_Button.configure(background = "White")
            Boss_2_Button.configure(background = "White")
            Name.configure(background = "Red")
            Settings_Config["Appearence"]["Game"]["Boss_Ship_Image"] = "Images\\Boss_Space_Ship(" + str(Number) + ").png"
    
    def Save_Configures():
        if Change_Obj_Col_Box.get() == "Yes":
            Settings_Config["Appearence"]["Start"]["Change_Object_Colours"] = True
        else:
            Settings_Config["Appearence"]["Start"]["Change_Object_Colours"] = False
        if Start_Win_Bg_Box.get() == "Black":
            Settings_Config["Appearence"]["Start"]["Background_Colour"] = "#000000"
        else:
            Settings_Config["Appearence"]["Start"]["Background_Colour"] = "#000014"
        Settings_Config["Appearence"]["Game"]["Star_Appearence"] = Star_Appearence_Box.get()
        if Player_Speed_Box.get() == "High":
            Settings_Config["Game_Functionings"]["Player_Ship_Speed"] = 8
        elif Player_Speed_Box.get() == "Low":
            Settings_Config["Game_Functionings"]["Player_Ship_Speed"] = 2
        else:
            Settings_Config["Game_Functionings"]["Player_Ship_Speed"] = 4
        if Game_Win_Bg_Box.get() == "Black":
                Settings_Config["Appearence"]["Game"]["Background_Colour"] = "#000000"
        else:
            Settings_Config["Appearence"]["Game"]["Background_Colour"] = "#000014"
        print(Settings_Config)
        Configurations = Settings_Config
        Configurations = json.dumps(Configurations)
        Configuration_File = open("Space_Shooter_Configurations.json", "w")
        print(Configurations)
        print(type(Configurations))
        Configuration_File.write(Configurations)
        Show_Configs()
        
    def Set_Defaults():
        Configurations = {
            "Appearence": 
                {
                "Start": 
                    {
                    "Change_Object_Colours": True,
                    "Background_Colour": "#000014"
                },
                "Game": 
                    {
                    "Player_Ship_Image": "Images\\Player_Space_Ship(1).png",
                    "Enemy_Ship_Image": "Images\\Enemy_Space_Ship(1).png",
                    "Boss_Ship_Image": "Images\\Boss_Space_Ship(1).png",
                    "Star_Appearence": "Stars with Movement",
                    "Background_Colour": "#000014"
                }
            },
        "Game_Functionings":
            {
                "Player_Ship_Speed": 4
            }
        }
        Configurations = json.dumps(Configurations)
        Configuration_File = open("Space_Shooter_Configurations.json", "w")
        Configuration_File.write(Configurations)
        Show_Configs()
    
    def Show_Configs():
        Configuration_File = open("Space_Shooter_Configurations.json", "r") # Here
        Configuration_File.seek(0)
        Configurations = Configuration_File.read()
        if Configurations:
            print("Filled")
        else:
            print("Empty")
        Configurations = json.loads(Configurations)
        
        Player_1_Button.configure(command = lambda: Change_Settings("Player", Player_1_Button, 1), background = Show_Curen_Config("Button", "Player", "Images\\Player_Space_Ship(1).png"))
        Player_2_Button.configure(command = lambda: Change_Settings("Player", Player_2_Button, 2), background = Show_Curen_Config("Button", "Player", "Images\\Player_Space_Ship(2).png"))
        Player_3_Button.configure(command = lambda: Change_Settings("Player", Player_3_Button, 3), background = Show_Curen_Config("Button", "Player", "Images\\Player_Space_Ship(3).png"))
        Enemy_1_Button.configure(command = lambda: Change_Settings("Enemy", Enemy_1_Button, 1), background = Show_Curen_Config("Button", "Enemy", "Images\\Enemy_Space_Ship(1).png"))
        Enemy_2_Button.configure(command = lambda: Change_Settings("Enemy", Enemy_2_Button, 2), background = Show_Curen_Config("Button", "Enemy", "Images\\Enemy_Space_Ship(2).png"))
        Enemy_3_Button.configure(command = lambda: Change_Settings("Enemy", Enemy_3_Button, 3), background = Show_Curen_Config("Button", "Enemy", "Images\\Enemy_Space_Ship(3).png"))
        Boss_1_Button.configure(command = lambda: Change_Settings("Boss", Boss_1_Button, 1), background = Show_Curen_Config("Button", "Boss", "Images\\Boss_Space_Ship(1).png"))
        Boss_2_Button.configure(command = lambda: Change_Settings("Boss", Boss_2_Button, 2), background = Show_Curen_Config("Button", "Boss", "Images\\Boss_Space_Ship(2).png"))
        Start_Win_Bg_Box.current(Show_Curen_Config("Combobox", Configurations["Appearence"]["Start"]["Background_Colour"]))
        Star_Appearence_Box.current(Show_Curen_Config("Combobox", Configurations["Appearence"]["Game"]["Star_Appearence"]))
        Game_Win_Bg_Box.current(Show_Curen_Config("Combobox", Configurations["Appearence"]["Game"]["Background_Colour"]))
        Player_Speed_Box.current(Show_Curen_Config("Combobox", Configurations["Game_Functionings"]["Player_Ship_Speed"]))
        Change_Obj_Col_Box.current(Show_Curen_Config("Combobox", Configurations["Appearence"]["Start"]["Change_Object_Colours"]))
        
    Show_Configs()
    
    Settings_Window.bind("<Control-s>", lambda event: Save_Configures())
    Settings_Window.bind("<Control-d>", lambda event: Set_Defaults())
    
    Settings_Window.mainloop()
```

Okk, this is a piece of my code (As I don't think that it would affect my problem), so my problem is that when the `Show_Config()` function is called for the first time, it works properly as I want, but for the second time when called (After pressing Ctrl-s/Ctrl-d), the `open("Space_Shooter_Configurations.json", "r").read()` returns empty string causing an error in the `Configurations = json.loads(Configurations)` line.

I got to know it after performing if-else-print debugging which finally made me understand that the second time, the Configurations variable was assigned to be an empty string.

As you can see, I'd tried `Configuration_File.seek(0)` method as well as reopening the file, but it didn't help.

Version: Python 3.8.6

IDE: Visual Studio Code

OS: Windows 7 (32-bits)

Comment: Are you sure the `Main_Frame` has focus? Try saying `Main_Frame.focus()` first.

Comment: No, it had no effect...

Comment: You have not provided enough code to test the issue. Without the tkinter frame and basic mainloop code we cannot test the issue ourselves. All we can do is guess at this point. Please update your question to include basic imports and a simple version of your issue that can be ran.

Comment: Okk, I edited my questions with full code.

Comment: You aren't adding the `self.` prefix when binding the class methods for the function keys (as you did for `"<Button-1>"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `Start_Game` in your bind referring to something in the global namespace but you should be referring to `self` instead.

There is no reason to try to call a method that is inside the same class by referring to its variable name in the global namespace.

In short:

This:

```
    Main_Frame.bind("<Button-1>", self.Start_Game_Event)
    Main_Frame.bind("<F1>", Start_Game.Show_Info)
    Main_Frame.bind("<F2>", Start_Game.Info_About)
    Main_Frame.bind("<F3>", Start_Game.Info_Game_Play)
```

Should be this:

```
    Main_Frame.bind("<Button-1>", self.Start_Game_Event)
    Main_Frame.bind("<F1>", self.Show_Info)
    Main_Frame.bind("<F2>", self.Info_About)
    Main_Frame.bind("<F3>", self.Info_Game_Play)
```

That all said you should look into the PEP8 Python standard. This will help clean up you code a bit. Next I would do `import tkinter as tk` instead of `from tkinter import *` this will help you prevent unwanted overwriting of existing function/variables by mistake.